# WPF: Include namespace in style resources to access Converters

Tags: wpf, namespaces

i'm confused as to why this is not working as I have looked at many examples and as far as I can tell im doing everything the same!

Below I have got a separate xaml file which is in `Project > Styles > Misc.xaml`. I'm trying to reference a namespace so that I can use the class (Converter) within this class in a style.

**P.S** I have tried adding the assembly name, this doesn't work still, all the files are within the same assembly.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test_Project.Styles"
                    xmlns:General="clr-namespace:Test_Project.Converters.General;assembly=Test_Project"
                    xmlns:CircularProgress="clr-namespace:Test_Project.Converters.CircleProgress">

    <FontFamily x:Key="FontAwesome">/Fonts/#FontAwesome</FontFamily>

    <!--<General:CheckBoxConverter x:Key="CheckBoxConverter" />-->
    <CircularProgress:StartPointConverter x:Key="StartPointConverter" />
```

The `xmlns:CircularProgress` declaration doesn't return any errors, however the last line returns the following error:

> The name "StartPointConverter" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:Test_Project.Converters.CircleProgress".

The namespace which i'm attempting to reference is located in `Project > Converters > CircleProgress.cs`, below is the code for this namespace:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace Test_Project.Converters
{
    public class StartPointConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value is double && ((double)value > 0.0))
            {
                return new Point((double)value / 2, 0);
            }

            return new Point();
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return Binding.DoNothing;
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone please explain to me what i'm doing wrong!? Thanks.

**Edit:**
Changed

`namespace Test_Project.Converters.CircleProgress`

to

`namespace Test_Project.Converters`

And changed the xmlns declaration to

`xmlns:CircularProgress="clr-namespace:Test_Project.Converters"`

to correspond, still get the same error.

**Edit 2**
Updated my Class code above, I have got `using System.Globalization;`, I probably should of included that in the first place sorry.

So still getting the error, here is my Project layout, I have selected the two files which I mention above:
[image]

Comment: Did you try to add the assembly on xmlns? like the one from 'General'?

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the class file you have added the converter, you missed:

```
using System.Globalization;
```

Or you need (take note of the last argument):

```
 public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
```

Oh by the way,  you have a similar post? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33439436/wpf-referencing-namespace-not-working

Comment: See my updated post, and I forgot about that post, sorry.

Comment: I have referenced this, it is `System.Drawing, however that isn't returning an error anyway.

Comment: I think for some reason, there are missing references on your converter class, because it is working.

Comment: Can't work out what though, I have tried following what this guy has done and it still doesn't work! http://dragablz.net/2015/09/15/bending-the-wpf-progressbar/

Comment: It now works all of a sudden, I didn't make any changes since rebuilding the solution multiple times, it just decided to start to work.

Answer (score 1):

Your namescpace does not correspond to file location.

```
namespace Test_Project.Converters.CircleProgress
```

should be

```
namespace Test_Project.Converters
```

Comment: Did you try rebuild project?

Comment: Yes, I have clicked "Clean Solution" and then "Rebuild Solution" and it displays the same error message.

Comment: I can't imagine what happens. Your code looks correct. Does you dictionary placed in the same project with converters?